# iOS not receiving post notifications (firebase - topics)

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, capacitor

For some reason, my iOS app does not seem to get notifications when using capacitor-community/fcm to subscribe to a topic. The same code works on Android.

The iOS app only receives notifications sent from the Firebase console to a specific user segment (app).

I have tried debugging and if I am not mistaken the code does not seem to subscribe to the topic on iOS.

I am using Ionic 6 (Angular), and Capacitor 5.

any help is appreciated.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ActionPerformed, PushNotificationSchema, PushNotifications, Token } from '@capacitor/push-notifications';
import { Preferences } from '@capacitor/preferences';
import { FCM } from '@capacitor-community/fcm';

interface SubscriptionPreferences {
  [key: string]: boolean;
}


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {
 
  subscriptionPreferences: SubscriptionPreferences = {};
  topics = ['Announcements', 'Calendar', 'Upcoming-Events', 'Block-Rotation', 'Clubs', 'Sports', 'Cafeteria', 'Contests', 'University-Advising', 'New-Student-Help', 'Parent-Info', 'Staff-Directory', 'ios'];

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('Initializing HomePage');

    PushNotifications.requestPermissions().then(result => {
      if (result.receive === 'granted') {
        // Register with Apple / Google to receive push via APNS/FCM
        PushNotifications.register();
      } else {
        // Show some error
      }
    });


    Preferences.get({ key: 'firstTimeOpen' }).then(result => {
      const isFirstTimeOpen = result.value;

      if (isFirstTimeOpen === null || isFirstTimeOpen === 'true') {
        this.topics.forEach(topic => {
          FCM.subscribeTo({ topic: topic })
            .then(() => {
              console.log(`Subscribed to topic ${topic}`);
              this.subscriptionPreferences[topic] = true;
              Preferences.set({ key: 'firstTimeOpen', value: 'true' });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              Preferences.set({ key: 'firstTimeOpen', value: 'false' });
            });
        });

        this.subscriptionPreferences = this.topics.reduce((acc: SubscriptionPreferences, topic: string) => {
          acc[topic] = true;
          return acc;
        }, {});

        Preferences.set({ key: 'subscriptionPreferences', value: JSON.stringify(this.subscriptionPreferences) });
      } 
       Preferences.get({ key: 'subscriptionPreferences' }).then(result => {
         const preferencesValue = result.value;
         this.subscriptionPreferences = preferencesValue ? JSON.parse(preferencesValue) : {};
        });
        console.log(this.subscriptionPreferences)
      
    });

    PushNotifications.addListener('registration', (token: Token) => {
      console.log('Push registration success, token: ' + token.value);
    });

    PushNotifications.addListener('registrationError', (error: any) => {
      console.log('Error on registration: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
    });

    PushNotifications.addListener(
      'pushNotificationReceived',
      (notification: PushNotificationSchema) => {
        alert('Notification received: ' + notification.title + '\n' + notification.body);
      },
    );

    PushNotifications.addListener(
      'pushNotificationActionPerformed',
      (notification: ActionPerformed) => {
        console.log('Push action performed: ' + JSON.stringify(notification));

        if (notification.notification) {
          const notificationData = notification.notification.data;
          if (notificationData && notificationData.page) {
            this.router.navigateByUrl(notificationData.page);
          }
        }
      },
    );
  }

}
```